# Same state in angular with different reducer

Tags: spartacus-storefront

we are written new action and a new reducer,
new reducer will update the existing state (product state)
how to call new reducer when a new action is dispatched and old reducer for old action, but both reducers has to update the same state

Answer (score 3):

If old reducer and action is ok, you shouldn't worry about them. Please create your own action with different type and provide own reducer, based on original one (I mean you can't override function as class, so my proposal is to copy-paste existing one from source code), with your new case which supports that action.
`StoreModule.forFeature(XXX_FEATURE, yourReducerToken)`